# Allow users to create their own salt for their passwords

Tags: php, hash, passwords

At the moment, my system is using a custom generate salt when the user registers which is then stored in the database along with their hashed password.

Now, I was thinking about having an option for users to define their own salt on registration. For an example, if they visit register2, they see 3 inputs:

Registerpage:

**Email**

**Password**

**Custom Salt**

So they fill out their email, password and set a custom salt-- whatever they want to be, in the limits of the hash function

```
$loginhash = hash_hmac('sha256',$password,$userdefinedsalt); //just for the post don't use
```

now, because they user has generated their own salt, that salt doesn't actually store in the database, only the hashed password.

Now the user has registered, every time they want to login, they must specify that custom salt they have created that hash with, use a POST get the inputs, hash them together and compare the passwords.

So if a malicious hacker somehow finds a way in to the database, they will have a useless hashed password, and no salt, therefore rendering that password useless? Yes or no?

Now, if another user doesn't feel like doing this, they can go the route of the system generated salt, that stores in the database etc.

Does this seem fesable for protecting users passwords?

**What if a user forgets their salt?**

They can go to the password reset, which will generate a custom hashed password with a salt, they can then login, and again perform the actions of creating another password with their salt, when doing so, it deletes the computer generated salt from the database to leave that blank.

Is this just asking for a world of hurt, is this a bad way?

Comment: Considering that you are not storing the salt on the database, it doesn't look like a bad idea. However, what kind of people would be using the system, who are you targeting? I mean, are you sure that they wanna like it because they will feel safer, or do you think it is possible for they find it just more complicated than it should be?

Comment: If I saw a website that asked me for the salt for the password on their registration page, I would question their capabilities. If I saw it on their login page, I'd close the browser and forget they ever existed. Forever.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams same reaction I would expect from most people.

Comment: Asking user for salt is equal with asking user to define two passwords. -- useless thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's the purpose of the salt, to prevent an attacker from getting all passwords with one single rainbow-table, nothing more nothing less. So better let the salt do its work and do not mix up different goals. Letting the user choose his own salt could even hurt security, because the user could choose a weak salt, which is not unique or is too short.

Asking for a user defined salt is just like asking for a second password, you wouldn't do that, would you? You *could* increase security this way, but then i would use the second password to encrypt (two-way) the calculated password-hash.

Better in my opinion is when you define a server side strong key, and use it to encrypt the password-hashes. Then the attacker cannot brute-force the hashes, until he gets additional privileges on the server to read the key.